# Solving system of second order ODEs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the system of second order ODEs:

```
A*u(t) + B*u''(t) = q(t) + b_A + b_B.
```

Here, A and B are known matrices, b_A is a known vector, b_B is a known vector, and q(t) is a time dependent vector which I can compute for a given t-value.

The goal of my problem is to numerically approximate the functions u_1 , ... , u_n, which are entries in u(t). Also, u''(t) denotes the second time derivative of u(t). I also have the initial condition vector:

```
u0 = zeros(n,1).
```

How would I solve this problem using MATLABs built in ode solvers (ode45)?

All of the examples I have seen thus far involve converting the system of second order ODEs into a system of first order ODEs, but they have all been very small examples. Thanks for the help.

---

To convert this into a system of first order ODEs, I would do

```
y_1 = u
y_2 = u', so :

y_1' = y_2, and 
y_2' = A^(-1)*(q(t) + b_A + b_B - A*y_1).
```

How should I implement this in MATLAB?